# What does 'real-valued' function mean in topology?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

If I have a topological space $X$ and a 'real-valued' function $f$ on $X$. Does this mean I have a map of the form: $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ where $\mathbb R$ has the usual topology? Or something else?

This may seem obvious but somehow it's unclear to me.

Comment: Yes, it means exactly that. What else could it mean?

Comment: I was struggling to think of anything else it could mean, but ought to clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I disagree with Mason. I have only ever seen the phrase "real-valued function on $X$" mean a function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-valued_function) seems to support my claim.

Comment: At least for the last 50 years or so, "real-valued" means "taking values in the real numbers", in my observation. Of course, usage may change in the future...

Answer (score -2):

'real valued' implies that the image is going to be a real number or vector in the n-dimensional reals. It doesn't necessarily imply that the image has the usual topology, or even that the image is all of the reals.

Comment: I have never seen real valued mean a function $f:\_ \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ except when $n=1$.